# Using 2 buttons to call 2 different js functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to use 2 buttons on my form, one to save the edited form and the other to save and e-mail a user with a canned message via a function called mailhandler.php. When either button is clicked it just resets the form and doesn't save it or email. There are 3 files, the index.php, webapp.js, and data.php. Data.php queries everything and is working fine, the problem seems to be with my JS. The 2 functions save() and email() are identical except email also has the emailFunction() function in it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The index.php file looks like this:

```
<button type="submit" id="btn1" onClick="save()">Save Report</button>
<button type="submit" id="btn2" onClick="email()">Save and E-Mail Report</button>
```

and webapp.js is this:

```
function emailFunction() {
window.open("MailHandler.php");
}
$(document).ready(function(){
// On page load: datatable
var table_records = $('#table_records').dataTable({
"ajax": "data.php?job=get_records",
"columns": [
{ "data": "c_customer_number" },
{ "data": "c_customer_name",   "sClass": "c_customer_name" },
{ "data": "functions",      "sClass": "functions" }
],
"aoColumnDefs": [
  { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-1] }
],
"lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
"oLanguage": {
  "oPaginate": {
    "sFirst":       " ",
    "sPrevious":    " ",
    "sNext":        " ",
    "sLast":        " ",
  },
  "sLengthMenu":    "Records per page: _MENU_",
  "sInfo":          "Total of _TOTAL_ records (showing _START_ to _END_)",
  "sInfoFiltered":  "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
}
  });
var form_record = $('#form_record');
form_record.validate();
// Show message
// Save button
$(document).on('click', '.function_edit a', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
// Get information from database
show_loading_message();
var id      = $(this).data('id');
var request = $.ajax({
  url:          'data.php?job=get_record',
  cache:        false,
  data:         'id=' + id,
  dataType:     'json',
  contentType:  'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  type:         'get'
});
request.done(function(output){
  if (output.result == 'success'){

    $('.lightbox_content h2').text('Edit Info');
    $('#form_record').attr('class', 'form edit');
    $('#form_record').attr('data-id', id);
    $('#form_record .field_container label.error').hide();
    $('#form_record 
.field_container').removeClass('valid').removeClass('error');
    $('#form_record #c_customer_name').val(output.data[0].c_customer_name);
    $('#form_record 
#c_customer_number').val(output.data[0].c_customer_number);
    hide_loading_message();
    show_lightbox();
  } else {
    hide_loading_message();
    show_message('Information request failed', 'error');
  }
});
request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
  hide_loading_message();
  show_message('Information request failed: ' + textStatus, 'error');
});
});
// Edit submit form
function save(){ 
$(document).on('ready', '#form_record', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
// Validate form
if (form_record.valid() == true){
  // Send information to database
  hide_ipad_keyboard();
  hide_lightbox();
  show_loading_message();
  var id        = $('#form_record').attr('data-id');
  var form_data = $('#form_record').serialize();
  var request   = $.ajax({
    url:          'data.php?job=edit_record&id=' + id,
    cache:        false,
    data:         form_data,
    dataType:     'json',
    contentType:  'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type:         'get'
  });
  request.done(function(output){

  if (output.result == 'success'){
    // Reload datatable
    table_records.api().ajax.reload(function(){
      hide_loading_message();
      var c_customer_name = $('#c_customer_number').val();
        show_message("Info '" + c_customer_name + " edited/added successfully.", 'success');
//          emailFunction();
      }, true);

    } else {
      hide_loading_message();
      show_message('Edit request failed', 'error');
    }

  });
  request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
    hide_loading_message();
    show_message('Edit request failed: ' + textStatus, 'error');
  });
}
});
}
// save/email submit form
function email(){ 
$(document).on('ready', '#form_record', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
// Validate form
if (form_record.valid() == true){
  // Send information to database
  hide_ipad_keyboard();
  hide_lightbox();
  show_loading_message();
  var id        = $('#form_record').attr('data-id');
  var form_data = $('#form_record').serialize();
  var request   = $.ajax({
    url:          'data.php?job=edit_record&id=' + id,
    cache:        false,
    data:         form_data,
    dataType:     'json',
    contentType:  'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type:         'get'
  });
  request.done(function(output){

    if (output.result == 'success'){
      // Reload datatable
      table_records.api().ajax.reload(function(){
        hide_loading_message();
        var c_customer_name = $('#c_customer_number').val();
        show_message("Info '" + c_customer_name + " edited/added successfully.", 'success');
        emailFunction();
      }, true);

    } else {
      hide_loading_message();
      show_message('Edit request failed', 'error');
    }
});
  request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
    hide_loading_message();
    show_message('Edit request failed: ' + textStatus, 'error');
  });
}
});
}
});
```

Comment: in your save function remove $(document).on('ready', '#form_record', function(e){. One document.ready function is enough

Comment: I don't think you need `$(document).on('ready', '#form_record', function(e){` sort of implmentation in `save` and `email` method. Just remove that once and try

Comment: I made the changes but sadly it still just refreshes the site and doesn't make the edited change.